# ClearInterval() does not work immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a Carousel which uses the `setInterval()` to toggle between the tabs every 4 seconds.
I now want to stop this auto-toggle on click of any particular tab.

http://jsfiddle.net/qjmDU/10/ is the JS fiddle where I have my html and jQuery.
I am guessing that the problem is the following code being used in the wrong place. Please advise the corrections that you see fit.

```
$(this).on("click", function (event) {
   console.log("After clear interval" + stopVar);
   clearInterval(stopVar);    
});
```

Comment: What is your issue? And please, fix your jsfiddle

Comment: Please test your Fiddle before throwing it at us ;)

Comment: In your fiddle you havent even include jQuery

Comment: Here's a fiddle with the obvious stuff fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/qjmDU/14/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your interval never is defined!

Before `setInterval` there is this `if (timeToStand)` and timeToStand is never defined.

When you defined `timeToStand` it works.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the original fiddle which does work: http://jsfiddle.net/qjmDU/

`setInterval` returns a unique id for the interval you just set.

`clearInterval` expects the unique id returned from setInterval

So your code should look something like

```
stopVar = setInterval(...);

...

clearInterval(stopVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this!

```
var pid = setInterval(function(){ fnXPTO()},500);

function fnXPTO()
{
     // to do anything.... 
}
```

---

clear interval...

```
window.setTimeout(function(){

clearInterval(pid );

},2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for correcting the fiddle RobH.
user1886419, If you look at the fiddle jsfiddle.net/qjmDU/14, I am doing the same as you suggest, but the auto-toggle stops only after 1 cycle through all tabs, rather than stopping immediately, on click of a tab.

timeToStand is a variable passed in initCarousel()

Comment: Is anyone still online?

Comment: I only want to stop the auto toggle on click of a tab, not after a cycle of toggling through all available tabs. The correct link to the JSFiddle is jsfiddle.net/qjmDU/14